# Compiling specific apache module in VS2010

Tags: c, apache, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, lua

Over the last few days I've been tinkering with mod_pLua on Windows (https://sourceforge.net/projects/modplua/ or https://github.com/Humbedooh/mod_pLua).

The pre-built Windows binary works a treat, except it doesn't seem to have been compiled with mod_dbd support for database connectivity. The documentation suggests that to enable this feature you must compile with a certain tag, so I've been trying to compile the module in VS2010 - hoping that I'll be able to get mod_dbd support working at some point - but I've run in to a snag. It just will not compile.

What I've done so far:

- Included apache/include and apache/lib, which got rid of a lot of
  errors
- Included lauxlib.h, lua.h, luaconf.h and lualib.h from Lua 5.2, which got rid of a lot of errors
- Compiled a .lib file from Lua 5.2 sources and included it, which fixed a few errors

The errors I'm getting at the moment are:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_openlib referenced in function _lua_dbopen C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Projects\C\mod_plua\mod_plua.obj

And a plethora like this:

> IntelliSense: a value of type "const char *(*)(cmd_parms *cmd, void *cfg, const char *arg)" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "cmd_func"  c:\users\michael\desktop\projects\c\mod_plua\mod_plua.h 394 5

As I'm not a C/C++ native, I only have a vague idea of what's wrong, and have likely done something wrong in my attempts to fix the issue. If someone could guide me in the right direction (or better yet, write a little instructional on how to compile the module from start to finish) I would be so happy.

I've uploaded my VS2010 project files and source here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51243175/mod_plua_vs2010.7z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answer:

The primary reason for the failure to compile was the Lua .lib file. The Microsoft compiler does strange things when dealing with C code, so I got an appropriately compiled version of the .lib from the LuaBinaries SourceForge repository (http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/) - specifically, 5.2.3/Windows Libraries/Dynamic/lua-5.2.3_Win32_dll10_lib.zip (which is compiled for VS2010).

This didn't enable mod_dbd support, which requires headers and sources from the Apache APR project, but it did allow successful compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using mod_pLua really, I haven't worked on that for nearly 3 years ;) You should use mod_lua instead, which comes bundled with httpd and works pretty much the same way (although it does not support the php-like scripting that mod_pLua does)

For DBD specific setups (especially how to use it on Windows), see http://modlua.org/api/database

Comment: The php like scripting was exactly what I wanted, otherwise I would've used mod_lua or maybe luvit